# Mysql Query to get max value of tables using auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash, shell

Hey guys I'm using this query to get the maximum value of a table that uses auto increment

```
SELECT table_schema,
   table_name,
   data_type,
   ( CASE data_type
       WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 255
       WHEN 'smallint' THEN 65535
       WHEN 'mediumint' THEN 16777215
       WHEN 'int' THEN 4294967295
       WHEN 'bigint' THEN 18446744073709551615
     end >> IF(Locate('unsigned', column_type) > 0, 0, 1) ) AS MAX_VALUE
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema NOT IN ( 'MYSQL', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
                       )
   AND extra = 'auto_increment'"
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what the IF statement is doing.

```
end >> IF(Locate('unsigned', column_type) > 0, 0, 1) ) AS MAX_VALUE
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>>` operator is a bitwise right-shift.

An `INT UNSIGNED` for example has a max value of 4294967295, which is 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or 11111111111111111111111111111111 in base 2.

But the signed `INT` uses one of those bits for a sign bit, so the max value of a signed integer is 2147483647, which is 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or 011111111111111111111111111111111 in base 2.

Converting 11111111111111111111111111111111 to 011111111111111111111111111111111 can be done by a right-shift of 1 bit. The leftmost bit of the 32-bit word is filled in with a zero.

Now for the `IF`:  MySQL names the data type either as "int" or "int unsigned". So if the word "unsigned" is found by the string function `LOCATE()`, then the max value is the full range of 4294967295, so bit-shift it by 0 bits. Else "unsigned" does not appear in the data type name, and the int is signed, so bit-shift it by 1 bit.

Another way of stating this:

- Max `INT UNSIGNED` = 4294967295 = 11111111111111111111111111111111
- Max `INT` = 2147483647 = 011111111111111111111111111111111 = **4294967295 >> 1**

You may also be interested in a similar script I wrote: https://github.com/billkarwin/bk-tools/blob/master/pk-full-ratio.sql

Answer (score 0):

The double angle brackets (greater than signs) are a binary shift operator.  If the column type is an unsigned integer, for example, it will shift 1 position (which essentially squares the number), and if it is a regular signed integer, it will not shift at all.  A signed integer uses one bit to indicate whether the number of positive or negative. An unsigned integer uses that bit as part of the value, so it can hold a much higher max value, but cannot hold negative values at all.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The function 'Locate('unsigned', column_type)' is ran.  This checks to see if the string 'unsigned' appears in the column named 'column_type'.  The 'Locate' function will return the character offset/location of the first letter in 'unsigned' if found in 'column_type' or zero (0) if not found.  This result is tested to be greater than zero '> 0'.  If TRUE, then the next expression is returned, a zero (0) in the above case.  If FALSE, then the final expression is returned, a one (1).

In other languages, it may be written like this:

```
if( Lotate('unsigned', column_type) > 0 ) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```